# Is it possible to open up a php file in modal box instead of a new web page?

Tags: php, popup, dialog

I am passing an ID to a php file using the following code

```
echo "<a href='getID.php?id=".$row[0]."' ><img id='indPainting' src='".$num."' align='absmiddle' /></a> <br>        <div id='paintingName'>";
```

getID.php would open a new page. Is it possible to open that page in a modal box (dialog box) instead of that new page, with a close modal box button?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Modal plugin for jQuery. For example :

### NyroModal (http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/)

Download and install the plugin (you need jQuery), include javascript and css files.

Normally, you should have this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/nyroModal.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nyroModal.custom.js"></script>
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nyroModal-ie6.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

After that, add this small javascript code in your page or main javascript file.

```
$(function() {
  $('.nyroModal').nyroModal();
});
```

And modify your code to add the "nyroModal" css class in your link like this :

```
echo "<a href='getID.php?id=".$row[0]."' class="nyroModal"><img id='indPainting' src='".$num."' align='absmiddle' /></a> <br>        <div id='paintingName'>";
```

And, it's done, you have your page opened page in a modal box when you click on your link, with a close button ;)